# Create a ruby method that accepts a hash of parameters

Tags: ruby

I don't know how to create a ruby method that accepts a hash of parameters. I mean, in Rails I'd like to use a method like this:

```
login_success :msg => "Success!", :gotourl => user_url
```

What is the prototype of a method that accepts this kind of parameters? How do I read them?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you pass paramaters to a Ruby function in hash syntax, Ruby will assume that is your goal. Thus:

```
def login_success(hsh = {})
  puts hsh[:msg]
end
```

Comment: Can't I use something like login_success(*params)?

Comment: a * (aka splat operator) means that method accepts any number of args and will put them in an array called params. Deciding on whether to use it or not depends on what you're after. In the example you provided, a hash makes sense.

Comment: That says you are expecting any number of arguments.  Like `foo(1, :b, '3')`.  Also, you don't need the "={}" part of that.  this will work fine: def login_success(hash).  The above code just sets the default as an empty hash.

Answer (score 33):

A key thing to remember is that you can only do the syntax where you leave out the hash characters {}, if the hash parameter is the last parameter of a function.  So you can do what Allyn did, and that will work.  Also

```
def login_success(name, hsh)
  puts "User #{name} logged in with #{hsh[:some_hash_key]}"
end
```

And you can call it with

```
login_success "username", :time => Time.now, :some_hash_key => "some text"
```

But if the hash is not the last parameter you have to surround the hash elements with {}.

Answer (score 14):

With the advent of Keyword Arguments in [Ruby 2.0](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/) you can now do

```
def login_success(msg:"Default", gotourl:"http://example.com")
  puts msg
  redirect_to gotourl
end
```

In Ruby 2.1 you can leave out the default values,

```
def login_success(msg:, gotourl:)
  puts msg
  redirect_to gotourl
end
```

When called, leaving out a parameter that has no default value will raise an `ArgumentError`

Comment: You might also want to mention that you can leave out the default values in Ruby 2.1 to make the parameters required, e.g. `def login_success(msg:, gotourl:)` will result in an error being raised if you try to call `login_success` without both the `msg` and `gotourl` parameters being specified.

Answer (score 5):

Use one single argument. Ruby will transform the named values into a hash:

```
def login_success arg
 # Your code here
end

login_success :msg => 'Success!', :gotourl => user_url
# => login_success({:msg => 'Success!', :gotourl => user_url})
```

If you really want to make sure you get a hash, instead of the default ruby duck typing, then you would need to control for it. Something like, for example:

```
def login_success arg
  raise Exception.new('Argument not a Hash...') unless arg.is_a? Hash
  # Your code here
end
```