# Ruby hash to method arguments

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
hash = {
  key1:12,
  key2:78
}
```

And I want to transform hash into seperate arguments in this method like:

```
SomeClass.method(key1:12, key2:78)
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583423/create-a-ruby-function-that-accepts-a-hash-of-parameters

Comment: Note that you are overwriting the existing `method` method.

Comment: Now that Ruby 2.0 accepts named parameters, I think this is a great question.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has no named arguments like Objective-C, however you can emulate it passing a Hash.
In Ruby 1.9 this is even nicer, given the new Hash syntax.

```
SomeClass.some_method(key1:12, key2:78)
```

basically means that the `some_method` accepts a Hash as parameter

```
def SomeClass
  def some_method(args)
    p(args)
  end
end
```

Then if you call

```
SomeClass.some_method(key1: 12, key2: 78)
```

it actually means

```
SomeClass.some_method({ key1: 12, key2: 78 })
```

so it's equivalent to pass the hash

```
hash = {
  key1: 12,
  key2: 78,
}

SomeClass.some_method(hash)
```

Comment: Ok nice, I was confused by the new syntax but it seems logical to pass a hash. great